# Correct Position for Variable Error Label - Bootstrap / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a FORM with some Errors Labels in front of each input - at right.

I can control the correct position of each error using this:

```
if(element.attr("name") == "id"){
   error.css( "right", "-95px" );
   }
```

Then I can put the label exactly 2-3 pixels in front of each input.

But

THE PROBLEM:

- some inputs had 2 or 3 different errors message.
- each label has a different width (because some messages are short than others)

I can control each width with:

```
min-width: 100px;
max-width: 200px;
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-weight: normal;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Min/Max width + white-space(nowrap).

When I put the label "Right -100px" for ERROR1 - the message was show OK - 2-3 pixles outside the input.

when the message was changed to ERROR2 (biggest message with larger label) - the label was show INSIDE THE INPUT.

if the message was short, the label was show 10-12 pixels outside the input.

It happens because the label grow-up to the left - and not to the right..

How can I choose the correct direction for the label grow-up?

example:

put a point in the middle of the screen > today, the max-width goes from center to right.

how can I go from center to left?

Float?

Here is the https://jsfiddle.net/4v2br346/ (I think it's the better way to understand the problem.. :D )

Please, try the FULL NAME input.

tks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Using `margin-left` will help you . check this

JS

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
ElementWidth = parseFloat($(element).outerWidth()) + 7;
if (element.attr("name") == "id") {
       error.css("margin-left", ElementWidth + 'px');
}
if (element.attr("name") == "name") {
       error.css("margin-left", ElementWidth + 'px');
}
if (element.length) {
      error.insertAfter(element);
} else {
      error.insertAfter(element);
}
},
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ytpjuaw0/)

[image]

**Note : I added 7 px to width because of arrow.**

Comment: Hi @j-santosh! First of all tks a lot for your time and help! Great Idea, but - I didnt said before - I'm using "RIGHT" alignment because when I use "LEFT" alignment and change de gridview (try on your demo) - minimize the window and change the window size - the label position goes crazy.. With "RIGHT" position the label always appears on the correct place (but I had this issue with the size of the label) - If I change for "LEFT" - I correct the size issue, but dont work fine in multiples grids.. Any idea? Tks a lot! Daniel

Comment: you mean the error should not dislocate from its position ?

Comment: just add `input-group` class to the parent element of the `input` and use `margin-left:7px` for arrow. [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3y43fjkj/), label will never dislocate from input element. if this is what you want , then i'll update my answer.